# Unable to loop through cells

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I previously posted about some difficulties in running a loop. I made some adjustments to it. I am wondering what is wrong.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim DVariable As Date
    Dim RngFind As Range
    Dim MonthNo, YearNo As Integer
    Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date
    Dim PasteCell As Range
    Dim M As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("By Trader").Select
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws1.Name = "NEW"
    Set ws = Sheets("Macro")
    Sheets("Macro").Select
    M = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For M = 2 To M
            With Sheets("By Trader")
    'loop column N until last cell with value (not entire column)
                For Each Cell In .Range("N1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
                    If Cell.Value = M Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
                    .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NEW").Rows(Cell.Row)
                    End If
                Next M
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I am aiming to extract the entire row if there is a match in values  to another sheet.

Comment: i tried to add in another variable i but am stuck

Comment: This line `M = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`
no `ws` set, probly it should be ws1 and also You should declare ws1 as `Dim ws1 as worksheet`

Comment: @user12151877 You already posted this code and got the exact same suggestion as Teamothy is providing you with now (which is correct). Please consider all given advice before reposting your code.

Comment: and use option explicit and define all your variables. Good coding practice

Comment: i have edited the code, can you help me take a look?

Comment: `For M = 2 To M` is weird. This may causing the errors.

Comment: i changed it to i but still facing problems

Comment: There are very few lines of code here.  I recommend you step through each line using `F8` and see what happens, checking the value of your variables during each line.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `Next Cell` and an `End With`

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim DVariable As Date
    Dim RngFind As Range
    ' You need to declare every variable in the line. If you don't it will be declared as a variant instead of just your last declaration
    Dim MonthNo As Integer, YearNo As Integer
    Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date
    Dim PasteCell As Range
    Dim M As Long, i As Long, NoRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("By Trader").Select
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws1.Name = "NEW"
    Set ws = Sheets("Macro")
    ws.Select
    ' Changed variable to prevent erroneous errors
    NoRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For M = 2 To NoRow
            With Sheets("By Trader")
    'loop column N until last cell with value (not entire column)
                For Each Cell In .Range("N1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
                    If Cell.Value = M Then
                        ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
                    .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NEW").Rows(Cell.Row)
                    End If
                ' Missing the next two lines
                Next Cell
            End With
        Next M
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```